# How do you create a super key in a table?

Tags: postgresql, key, pgadmin

How do I make both the columns *sid* and *ccode* in the table below a super key when creating the table?:

```
Enrolled (sid integer, ccode varchar(6))
```

Here's what I've tried with but obviously SQL does not allow multiple primary keys to be declared this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled
(
sid integer,
ccode varchar(6),
CONSTRAINT enrolled_pkey1 PRIMARY KEY (sid),
CONSTRAINT enrolled_pkey2 PRIMARY KEY (ccode)
);
```

I'm using pgAdmin3 - Postgres.

Comment: A super key has more columns than is needed to identify each record. Why would you want that? Did you confuse the terms *key* and *index*?

Comment: Do you mean a *compound key*? Never heard the term *super key*.

Comment: Yes, I think the technical term is a compound key.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create *one* primary key over both columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled
(
    sid integer,
    ccode varchar(6),
    CONSTRAINT enrolled_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sid, code)
);
```

However, it is usually a good idea to keep a simple `serial`-type primary key and just use e.g. UNIQUE constraints for field or combination of fields that need to be unique.